# Метод onCreateView и его тонкости

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Рассматриваю некоторые приложения, и задался вопросом по поводу `onCreateView`. Так понимаю именно в нём мы создаём наши вьюшки для нашего фрагмента скажем?

Возможно ли такое, что из за большого кол-ва вьюшек в нашем фрагменте, мы будем перекрывать ими друг друга? Если да, то как избежать подобного?

Comment: Какую разметку сверстаете, так и будут расплогаться виджеты - их количество и метод `onCreateView()` никак на это не повлияют.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Рассматриваю некоторые приложения, и задался вопросом по поводу onCreateView. Так понимаю именно в нём мы создаём наши вьюшки для нашего фрагмента скажем?

В методе `onCreateView(...)` вызывается метод `inflate(...)` некоторого объекта класса `LayoutInflater`:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.%LAYOUT_ID%, container, false);
```

Этот метод преобразует `xml`-файл с разметкой (дерево элементов) в объект класса `View`, который можно явно преобразовать к корневому элементу `xml`-файла.

При этом, как правило, этот объект на самом деле является субклассом класса `View`, а не непосредственно им. Например, он может быть объектом класса `LinearLayout` или же `FrameLayout`.

Далее, путем вызова метода `view.findViewById(...)` происходит обход дочерних элементов представления `view`, пока не будет найдет виджет с заданным идентификатором. Когда виджет найден, метод `view.findViewById(...)` возвращает его (в виде объекта класса `View`, который потом явно кастуется к нужному типу).

> Возможно ли такое, что из за большого кол-ва вьюшек в нашем фрагменте, мы будем перекрывать ими друг друга? Если да, то как избежать подобного?

Да, возможно, и не обязательно из-за их большого количества.

Все экранные элементы можно позиционировать либо относительно родительского представления, либо относительно других представлений, находящихся на этом же уровне, либо относительно первого и второго одновременно (это зависит от родительского контейнера).

Чтобы не перекрывать элементы друг другом, необходимо их правильно позиционировать, путем установки тех или иных атрибутов позиционирования.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не ясен. Если располагать вьюхи внутри LinearLayout который внутри ScrollView то перекрытие в общем случае невозможно. Если же вы используете RelativeLayout  с относительным позиционированием то да - у вас всё поедет почти сразу